# POSIX compliant way of writing conditional operators

Tags: shell, posix, uid

In bash you can do

```
if [ $(echo $UID) != 0 ]
then
    echo "Run as root"
    exit
fi
```

This returns an error message when I run the script with dash or other POSIX-compliant shells. How do you do this in POSIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UID` is not defined for all shells (it's not a POSIX requirement)

You can use `id -u` instead:

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]
then
    echo "Run as root"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! So it wasn't my operators after all.

Comment: And when it is defined, you don’t need the `echo` in the sub shell.

Comment: I would probably `exit 1` as it's an error condition.